# .on 'click' function only working once, even though it is wrapped in a document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, onscroll

I have a second nav coming in on the scroll down, but when I click the nav link to get there, it disappears. I created the onclick function below, and that works, but it only works once....on the second click the nav bar does not reappear until a scroll takes place.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).on('scroll', function () {

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('#appear-nav').fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        $('#appear-nav').fadeOut(100);
      }

      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1100) {
         $('#appear-about').css('color','#b0eb00');
      } else {
         $('#appear-about').css('color','#ffffff');
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1900) {
         $('#appear-about').css('color','#ffffff');
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2150) {
        $('#appear-tech').css('color','#b0eb00');
      } else {
        $('#appear-tech').css('color','#ffffff');
      }
  });

  $('#appear-about').on('click', function() {
     $('#appear-nav').fadeIn(100);
     $(this).css('color','#b0eb00');
  });

  $('#appear-tech').on('click', function() {
     $('#appear-nav').fadeIn(100);
     $(this).css('color','#b0eb00');
  });
  $('#appear-home').on('click', function() {
     $('#appear-nav').fadeOut(100);
  });

  //end function
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="appear-nav">
  <ul class="appear-nav-ul">
    <li id="appear-home"><%= link_to "home", root_path %></li>
    <li>
      <a id="appear-about" href="/#first-home-image">about</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="appear-tech" href="/#second-home-image">tech</a>
    </li>
    <li><%= link_to "team", team_path %></li>
    <li>
      <a href="/"><img src="/assets/small-logo.png" id="appear-logo">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><%= link_to "projects", projects_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "news", about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "contact", contact_path %></li>
    <% if logged_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">Account<b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", 
                                      edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li class="divider">(divider)</li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: 
                                       :delete %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "login", login_path %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide your HTML code? why are you using more than one $(document).ready ??

Comment: `$(document).ready` and `$(function(){})` do the same things, tha last one is recommended.

Comment: Sounds like the expected behaviour, why would the element reappear when clicking again, when all the event handler does is fade it out

Comment: Added my code @JVLobo

Comment: I don't get your issue. if you click on Home, the navbar disappears, and them how do you want it to appear again? if the navbar is disappeared, you can't click on its elements...

Comment: @JVLobo if I click the 'tech' link on the nav bar that appears, after the second click it does not appear anymore, until scrolling starts. so for example after the second click on the '#about-nav' or '#about-tech' links, the fade in function doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#appear-nav').css('display', 'none');

  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
      $('#appear-nav').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
      $('#appear-nav').fadeOut(100);
    }
  });
});



$('#appear-tech', '#appear-about').on('click', function() {
   $('#appear-nav').fadeIn(50);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am still getting the same error. I posted the new code about in the original question section, along with the html